# react-image-cropper issue implemention

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have try implement react-image-cropper in my react.js project. But Image not load to show for crop issue.
Here I select the image using onSelectFile() function it take file but ReactCrop not load to image  for cropper

Here the way I added the react-image-cropper

```js
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
import ReactCrop from "react-image-crop";
import "react-image-crop/dist/ReactCrop.css";

import "./App.css";

function App() {
  const [src, setSrc] = useState(null);
  const [crop, setCrop] = useState({
    unit: "%",
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
  });
  const [croppedImageUrl, setCroppedImageUrl] = useState(null);
  const imageRef = useRef(null);

  const onSelectFile = (e) => {
    if (e.target.files && e.target.files.length > 0) {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.addEventListener("load", () => {
        setSrc(reader.result);
        // Reset the crop to default values when a new image is selected
        setCrop({
          unit: "%",
          x: 0,
          y: 0,
          width: 50,
          height: 50,
        });
      });
      reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
    }
  };

  const onImageLoaded = (image) => {
    imageRef.current = image;
  };

  const onCropComplete = (crop) => {
    makeClientCrop(crop);
  };

  const onCropChange = (crop) => {
    setCrop(crop);
  };

  const makeClientCrop = async (crop) => {
    if (imageRef.current && crop.width && crop.height) {
      const croppedImageUrl = await getCroppedImg(
        imageRef.current,
        crop,
        "newFile.jpeg"
      );
      setCroppedImageUrl(croppedImageUrl);
    }
  };

  const getCroppedImg = (image, crop, fileName) => {
    const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    const scaleX = image.naturalWidth / image.width;
    const scaleY = image.naturalHeight / image.height;
    canvas.width = crop.width;
    canvas.height = crop.height;
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    ctx.drawImage(
      image,
      crop.x * scaleX,
      crop.y * scaleY,
      crop.width * scaleX,
      crop.height * scaleY,
      0,
      0,
      crop.width,
      crop.height
    );

    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      canvas.toBlob((blob) => {
        if (!blob) {
          console.error("Canvas is empty");
          return;
        }
        blob.name = fileName;
        if (croppedImageUrl) {
          window.URL.revokeObjectURL(croppedImageUrl);
        }
        const imageUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        setCroppedImageUrl(imageUrl);
        resolve(imageUrl);
      }, "image/jpeg");
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <input type="file" accept="image/*" onChange={onSelectFile} />
      </div>
      {src && (
        <ReactCrop
          src={src}
          crop={crop}
          ruleOfThirds
          onImageLoaded={onImageLoaded}
          onComplete={onCropComplete}
          onChange={onCropChange}
        />
      )}
      {croppedImageUrl && (
        <img alt="Crop" style={{ maxWidth: "100%" }} src={croppedImageUrl} />
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Please provide the relevant solutions to me, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you have to create an image, as in this example:

```js
 let img = new Image();
 img.onload = ()=>{
    //Your code
 }
 img.src = "file://" + src;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<ReactCrop>` component doesn't have a `src` property.  You need to wrap it around an `<img />`.

Additionally, if you want to display a preview of the cropped image, you can draw the image directly to a canvas element ref.

Below is a simplified, annotated example.

```
import { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';

import ReactCrop from 'react-image-crop';
import 'react-image-crop/dist/ReactCrop.css';


const initialCropValues = {
  unit: '%',
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  width: 50,
  height: 50,
};

function App() {
  // original image src
  const [src, setSrc] = useState(null);
  // state to store onCropChange crop values (as percentages)
  const [crop, setCrop] = useState(initialCropValues);
  // state to store onCropComplete crop values (as pixels)
  const [completedCrop, setCompletedCrop] = useState(null);

  // ref for img element
  const imgRef = useRef(null);
  // ref for canvas element
  const canvasRef = useRef(null);

  const onSelectFile = (e) => {
    // if a file is selected
    if (e.target.files && e.target.files.length > 0) {
      // instantiate a FileReader
      const reader = new FileReader();
      // listen for the load event only once
      reader.addEventListener(
        'load',
        () => {
          // if the result is a string set it as the src state
          if (typeof reader.result === 'string') setSrc(reader.result);
          // reset the crop values
          setCrop(initialCropValues);
          // set the initial completed crop to clear the canvas
          // of a previous image crop, if any
          setCompletedCrop({
            unit: 'px',
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
            width: 0,
            height: 0,
          });
        },
        { once: true }
      );
      // read the file as a data url
      reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
    }
  };

  // set the crop values onCropChange
  const onCropChange = (crop) => setCrop(crop);

  // set the completed crop values onCropComplete
  const onCropComplete = (crop) => {
    setCompletedCrop(crop);
  };
  
  useEffect(() => {
    // return if there's no canvas element, image or crop values
    if (!canvasRef.current || !imgRef.current || !completedCrop) return;

    // reset the completed crop state
    setCompletedCrop(null);

    // destructure the crop values for convenience
    const { x, y, width, height } = completedCrop;

    // get the 2d context for the canvas element
    const ctx = canvasRef.current.getContext('2d');

    // make sure there is a context
    if (!ctx) return;

    // clear the canvas
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasRef.current.width, canvasRef.current.height);

    // set the canvas height and width to the crop size
    canvasRef.current.width = width;
    canvasRef.current.height = height;

    // calculate the original image scale
    const scaleX = imgRef.current.naturalWidth / imgRef.current.width;
    const scaleY = imgRef.current.naturalHeight / imgRef.current.height;

    // draw the cropped image to the canvas
    ctx.drawImage(
      imgRef.current,
      x * scaleX,
      y * scaleY,
      width * scaleX,
      height * scaleY,
      0,
      0,
      width,
      height
    );
    return () => {};
  }, [completedCrop, src]);
  
  return (
    <>
      <h1>React Image Crop</h1>
      <input type="file" accept="image/*" onChange={onSelectFile} />
      {src && (
        <ReactCrop
          crop={crop}
          ruleOfThirds
          onComplete={onCropComplete}
          onChange={onCropChange}
        >
          <img
            src={src}
            alt="Image to be cropped"
            style={{ maxHeight: '80vh' }}
            ref={imgRef}
          />
        </ReactCrop>
      )}
      <canvas ref={canvasRef} width={0} height={0} />
    </>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

`evt.target.files` is always going to be an Array, even if it's empty. so checking for `evt.target.files`
is unnecessary.

using the async FileReader API is also legacy, unnecessary and should be avoided.
converting things into base64 introduce a lot of overhead by converting the binary data into a string
and then back into binary data again.
a ObjectURL is just a pointer to where the file is located on the disc and reads faster and use less memory.

```js
const onSelectFile = evt => {
  const [ file ] = evt.target.files
  if (file) {
    setSrc(URL.createObjectURL(file))
    // reset the crop values
    setCrop(initialCropValues)
    // set the initial completed crop to clear the canvas
    // of a previous image crop, if any
    setCompletedCrop({
      unit: 'px',
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      width: 0,
      height: 0,
    })
  }
}
```